# python - argv function not working

Tags: python, argv

I have just started to study Python and I am now in the process of doing some exercises.

Specifically, this exercise asks to write a Python program to sum three given integers. However, if two values are equal sum will be zero.

This is my code:

```
   from sys import argv
   script, x, y, z = argv

   def sum(x, y, z):  
       if x == y or y == z or x==z:  
          sum = 0  
       else:  
          sum = x + y + z  
       return sum  
   print (sum)
```

I am opening the script in WindowPowerShell specifying the script name (es3.py) and the three variables, e.g: 1 2 3.

However I get the following message:

```
<function sum at 0x0000000001E0F048>
```

instead of the result I was expecting.

Does anyone have any ideas of why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this is the message I get function sum at 0x0000000001E0F048

Comment: What are you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

Let me comment your code:

```
script, x, y, z = argv
# we now have four new variables inside the main module: 
# script, x, y, z
# all functions defined here have access to these but
# cannot modify them (unless we use "global").

def sum(x, y, z):
    # while sum() in principle has access to the 
    # variables defined outside of sum(),
    # sum() (the function) also takes three parameters.
    # these need to be passed in with a function call
    # (i.e. sum(x, y, z)).
    #
    # x, y, z here are unrelated to x, y, z outside of sum().
    # in fact the parameters shadow the global variables,
    # making them inaccessible (via direct means).
    if x == y or y == z or x==z:  
        sum = 0  
        # this defines a local variable "sum".
        # it is unrelated to the function "sum"
    else:  
        sum = x + y + z  
        # x, y, z are strings, so "sum" is now a string, too.
    return sum

print (sum)
# here, you refer to the function "sum".
# the variable "sum" only exists inside the function "sum".
```

If you want the result of `sum()` (the function), you need call it with parameters:

```
print(sum(x, y, z))
```

You cannot access the variable `sum` outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you

```
print(sum)
```

then you print the *function* `sum`.

If you want to print the result, you must *call* `sum`:

```
print(sum(x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print (sum(x,y,z))
```

means call your function/method and print the return value.

```
print (sum)
```

means print the meta data of your data(sum is also a type of data)

Answer (score 0):

You should print the result of the `sum` function :

```
print(sum(x, y, z))
```

This way the return value of the `sum` function will be printed out. The way you did it, just prints out a function reference.

*Also as a side note, that `sum()` is a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) python function, so it's best to avoid naming conflicts and name your functions accordingly.*

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
from sys import argv
script, x, y, z = argv

def sum_(x, y, z):  
    if x == y or y == z or x==z:  
        the_sum = 0  
    else:  
        the_sum = int(x) + int(y) + int(z)  
    return the_sum  
print(sum_(x, y, z))
```